# Normalisation to 3NF

Tags: database, database-normalization

I am currently trying to normalise a set of data for my coursework. I believe I have managed to get everything to 3NF bar this one table as I think it still has a transitive dependency. Also it has an empty set of data.

```
ENTRÉE_CODE  ENTRÉE_DESC    ENTRÉE_COST
E3           Salmon Fillet  18.95
E5           12oz Ribeye    
E7           8oz Fillet     21.95
```

Anyone got any ideas? I cant find anything online for sets with empty cells

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & ask 1 specific question re the first place you are stuck. PS [What to do with null values when modeling and normalizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40733625/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it matters about your empty fields, especially in a number (int, decimal) column. there is nothing you can do to normalise that further.
One suggestion I may make would be for splitting up the description.
you could reference a new table with 'meat type' e.g. salmon, beef, pork, etc.
you could also reference a table for weight of the meat e.g. 8oz, 12oz. and again for the cut e.g. ribeye, fillet, rump. if indeed it is just meat on your entree menu.