# MySQL Normalization when column depends on 2 columns, of which exactly one is null

Tags: mysql, rdbms, database-normalization

[image]

In the `Person` table, either the `Citizen_IdentityID` or the `Foreigner_WorkPermitID` will be null.

The `PersonID_ID` holds either the value of the `Citizen_IdentityID` or `Foreigner_WorkPermitID` (whichever that is not null).

In other words, `PersonID_ID` is dependent on the value of either `Citizen_IdentityID` or `Foreigner_WorkPermitID`.

How should I structure the design for normalization?

The above entities are just a simple substitution of the actual use case.

Comment: This is an antipattern for database subtyping. Have you googled your title? Re "normalization", what is your reference? What does it say about normalizing NULLs? Have you googled normalization when there are NULLs? How would you normalize if NULL was just another value? Why haven't you mentioned FDs? Do FKs have anything to do with normalization? PS Your title is not your question. Please google many clear, precise specific phrasings of your actual question plus tags. If you still need to ask use one of those phrasings as a title. (How else ought you research your question or title it?)

Comment: Which part of it is an antipattern? Edited the title.

Comment: Google your title & my 1st sentence. Please address my previous comment. Editing your title is a tiny part of it. And it comes after doing a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: PS I just googled 'database how to normalize with nulls' and my *third hit* is SO [What to do with null values when modeling and normalizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40733477/3404097) which has an answer [*by me*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733477/what-to-do-with-null-values-when-modeling-and-normalizing). (But I doubt you really mean to ask anything about normalizing here.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just create one table `person`,

Having following columns

```
id int auto increment
citizen_id int
workpermit_id int
name varchar
```

So that whenever there is need to use one of id between `citizen_id` or `workpermit_id` you can simply check it's absence by suing `isnull()`

Comment: But i have other attributes that depends only on `ID`, eg. `IDColor`. How would i normalize that?