# NULL value in composite primary key

Tags: sql, database-design, database-normalization, composite-primary-key, erd

I have some pretty complex data that I have organised in a table with columns similar to below:

```
|| id_1 || id_2 || id_3 || id_4 || quantity ||
```

id_1 and id_2 will always be NON-NULL, but at least one of id_3 and id_4 will be NULL, deciding which other table to join to. Is it possible to have a composite primary key of id's 1-4 knowing that at least one of them will be NULL? Or is this a poor design for a table?

Comment: Is 'possible *and* poor' an acceptable response?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do with null values when modeling and normalizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733477/what-to-do-with-null-values-when-modeling-and-normalizing)

Comment: This is a common anti-pattern for subtyping/inheritance/polymorphism. [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097) Also (as one can expect) a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Comment: A primary key column by definition must be defined as NOT NULL

Comment: Thank you philipxy, this was exactly what i'm looking for

Comment: You can click to agree that this is a duplicate. PS Follow a published academic information modeling & DB design textbook/reference. PS See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter `x` re a comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified.

Comment: @JSBach Not possible given the tags. In SQL PK means UNIQUE NOT NULL constraintwise.