# why empty values are allowed but not null values in composite primary keys

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, primary-key, composite-key

I am working on an App connecting to the Snowflake database. I stumbled upon an issue while loading CSV files. I was using the NULL_IF condition in [copy command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html) to change column value to null if any empty value is encountered during the load

On investigation, I came to know that one of the columns is part of the composite primary key, and the value for this column was empty in a few rows. after I removed the NULL_IF condition, It started working fine.

*Why empty values are allowed but not null values in composite primary keys?*

I searched a lot, but all the answers are trying to explain why a composite key column can not have null values and it somewhat makes sense. But then why empty value is considered legit? Can somebody please explain? Thanks

**example:**

```
CREATE TABLE table_employee (
    column1 Varchar2(255),
    column2 Varchar2(255),
    column3 Varchar2(255),
    primary key (column1, column2)
   ....
);
```

Following Insert will succeed:

```
INSERT INTO table_employee(column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES ('', 'abc', '', ...);
```

Following Insert will fail:

```
INSERT INTO table_employee(column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (null, 'abc', '', ...);
```

Comment: "why a composite key column can not have null values and it somewhat makes sense". If that makes sense to you, you should also understand why `''` *is* allowed (I assume you mean empty string when you say empty values). `''` Is a value, `null` is not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do with null values when modeling and normalizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733477/what-to-do-with-null-values-when-modeling-and-normalizing)

Comment: "empty" is not clear. A row & column cell with a null is not "empty". Null is not the empty string in standard SQL. (It's a default in Oracle SQL.) PS Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: @philipxy this doesn't answer what I am looking for. please re-read my query. I had already mentioned in my question that there are so many articles explaining why NULL can't be inserted in the composite key. let me put my question this way. why different treatment for empty value as compared to null? in my opinion, if null is not allowed in the composite key, Neither should "Empty" value be.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS "Why" is usually a bad & vague way to phrase a question. If you want to know why your expectations are not met in terms of the language definition, you need to give your expectations & why--and to have done reasonable research, with justification per authoritative documentation; and you are really what the language is defined to be. But you could just as well be asking why the language designers decided to include a given feature. (Eventually you did give code.) PS Say "the empty string", "empty" is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

> *why empty value is considered legit*

[Empty Strings and NULL Values](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-considerations.html#empty-strings-and-null-values)

> **An empty string is a string with zero length or no characters**, whereas **NULL values represent an absence of data.**

Thus an empty string is conceptually different than `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to address why empty values are allowed but NULL values are prohibited in composite primary keys within Snowflake DB.

First of all, We need to understanding NULL vs. Empty Values:

- **NULL:** Represents a missing or unknown value. It's distinct from any other value, including itself (NULL = NULL evaluates to false).
- **Empty Value**: Denotes a value with zero content, but it's still a known value. Examples:
  Empty string (""), Zero (0) for numbers, Empty date ("0001-01-01")

**- Key Reasons for the Disparity**:

1. Primary keys unequivocally identify each row in a table.NULL's uncertainty makes it unsuitable for precise identification.
2. Composite primary keys guarantee uniqueness across multiple columns. NULL's ambiguous nature could lead to multiple rows with NULL values in those columns, violating uniqueness.
3. Foreign keys reference primary keys in other tables.Allowing NULL in primary keys could jeopardize referential integrity, as a NULL foreign key wouldn't definitively link to a specific row.
4. Snowflake's Handling of Column Null ability.When a primary key is defined, Snowflake implicitly sets all involved columns to NOT NULL, even if not explicitly specified.

**My 2 cents**: While empty strings are technically allowed in composite primary keys, their use often signals potential data quality issues or design flaws.
It's generally recommended to avoid empty values in primary keys whenever possible.